# Getting access to incrementing extension of file (as a integer variable)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I'm trying to code a simple script that uses **sed** to basic find&replace functionality.
I want to have original file **untouched** and have results in new files called "file.n" (n is being incremented).

My main problem is with numbering new files. This is basic code of mine that has static functionality for n=1 and n=2:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1

if [[ -f file.$n ]]
then sed -e 's/'$2'/'$3'/g' $1 > file.$((n+1))

else sed -e 's/'$2'/'$3'/g' $1 > file.1
fi
```

Input in terminal looks like: *./script text_sample.txt word_1 word_2*

This code works okay for first and second use (if file.1 hasn't existed, it's going to save results here; else it will be saved in file.(n+1) which is file.2).

But how do I make it for file.3, file.4 etc? After launching this script every single time, at start it's n=1 and I don't really have more ideas how I can deal with it.

I've already tried some export variables, using specific variable as a command (to make this integer more like global); I guess some loops might be needed...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1

while [[ -f file.$n ]]; do
    n=$((n+1)
done

sed -e 's/'$2'/'$3'/g' $1 > "file.${n}"
```

Comment: oh it was that simple! I'm very beginner at bash so thank you, works like a charm :)

Comment: admittedly it's neither the most elegant nor robust solution, but it's simple and it should work reasonably well if you're not working with too many files.

Answer (score 0):

sed has a backup feature
try `sed -i [SUFFIX]`

Comment: I know this feature, tested it initially but I don't think it's able to handle "file.n" syntax? For my application, it's a must to name new files the same but with incrementing numer as a extension.